# convergence radius and power series

Tags: analysis

Find the power series and convergence radius of $f(z)=\frac{1}{1+z^2} $ in $z=1$.

I tried to start with Taylor series, but couldn't find the representation. Is there a trick here?
Thanks

Comment: Hint:  $\frac 1{1-x}=\sum x^n$

Comment: @lulu I think the OP wants to expand the Taylor series of f about 1, not 0.

Comment: @zhw Ah, missed that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac1{1+z^2}=-\frac1{2i}\left(\frac1{i-z}+\frac1{i+z}\right)=-\frac1{2i}\left(-\frac1{1-i+(z-1)}+\frac1{1+i+(z-1)}\right)=$$

$$=-\frac1{2i}\left(-\frac1{1-i}\frac1{1+\frac{z-1}{1-i}}+\frac1{1+i}\frac1{1+\frac{z-1}{1+i}}\right)=$$

$$=\frac1{2+2i}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{(z-1)^n}{(1-i)^n}+\frac1{2-2i}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{(z-1)^n}{(1+i)^n}=$$

The above, assuming

$$\left|\frac{z-1}{1\pm i}\right|<1\iff |z-1|<\sqrt2$$

Comment: I think your first inequality has an accidental sign change.

Comment: @user21820 Thank you. Not sure where/what you mean: in the last line?

Comment: Sorry sorry I meant "first equality". My brain is extremely careless =S

Comment: And it's probably easier to factorize as $\frac{1}{1+z^2} = \frac{1}{(1+zi)(1-zi)}$.

Comment: @user21820 Thank you, you're completely right. Funny thing, I remember I wrote it (or so I thought...) but somehow I erased or simply forgot to write it down. It doesn't affect greatly the development and radius and etc., but I shall edit it now.